# Why Hibernate tries to set and entity value of my id class?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key

I have tree tables look like this

```
Granma
----------------------------------------
grandmar_id VARCHAR (PK)


Mommy (One-To-One with Grandma)
----------------------------------------
grandmar_id VARHCAR (PK)


Baby (Many-To-One with Mommy)
----------------------------------------
grandmar_id VARCHAR (PK)
baby_no     BIGINT  (PK)
```

I wrote entities for `Grandma` and `Mommy` look like this.

```java
class Grandma {

    @Id String grandmaId;
}


class Mommy implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "grandma_id")
    Grandma grandma;
}
```

And I prepared `Baby` and `BabyId` look like this.

```java
@Data
class BabyId implements Serializable {

    // Hibernate tries to set this field with an instance of Mommy
    String mommy;

    Long babyNo;
}


@Entity
@IdClass(BabyId.class)
class Baby {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "grandma_id")
    Mommy mommy;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "baby_no")
    Long babyNo;
}
```

When I tried to persist an instance of `Baby`, Hibernate keep saying..

```
Could not set field value [Mommy(...] value by reflection :
    [class BabyId.mommy] setter of BabyId.mommy
```

Why JPA(Hiberate) wants to set an instance of `Mommy` on my `BabaId#mommy` field?

What did I do wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict regarding the `mommy` field in `Baby` and `BabyId` and the `@IdClass` and `@ManyToOne` annotations.

On one hand, the `@IdClass(BabyId.class)` requires the fields `String mommy` and `Long babyNo` annotated with `@Id` on the class `Baby`.

On the other hand, the `@ManyToOne Mommy  mommy` declares the `mommy` field as `Mommy` reference on the `Baby` class.

Thus, two `mommy` fields would be needed, one `@Id String mommy` and one `@ManyToOne Mommy mommy`.

Renaming one of the `mommy` fields will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure following solution is Hibernate-specific.

I commented out the `@IdClass(BabyId.class)` and make the `Baby` class implements `Serializable`.

```java
@Deprecated
@Data
class BabyId implements Serializable {

    // Hibernate tries to set this field with an instance of Mommy
    String mommy;

    Long babyNo;
}


@Entity
// @IdClass(BabyId.class)
class Baby implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "grandma_id")
    Mommy mommy;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "baby_no")
    Long babyNo;
}
```

UPDATE

Here comes another working image according to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62673061/330457).

```
@Data
class BabyId implements Serializable {

    String grandmaId;

    Long babyNo;
}


@Entity
// @IdClass(BabyId.class)
class Baby implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "grandma_id")
    private String grandmaId;

    //@Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "grandma_id")
    Mommy mommy;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "baby_no")
    Long babyNo;
}
```